# Caused by: intradoc.data.DataException: !csJdbcGenericError | Oracle webcenter webservice

Tags: oracle, web-services, oracle11g, webcenter, stellent

I'm getting this error !csServiceDataException,GET_WORKFLOW_HISTORY_EMAIL_DETAILS,QWorkflowHistoryEmailDetails!$ exception backtrace:intradoc.common.ServiceException: !csServiceDataException,GET_WORKFLOW_HISTORY_EMAIL_DETAILS,QWorkflowHistoryEmailDetails!$
 services/3 *ScriptStack GET_WORKFLOW_HISTORY_EMAIL_DETAILS."**Caused by: intradoc.data.DataException: !csJdbcGenericError**" while executing a custom service in oracle webcenter. let me know what i 'm missing. if query & service i'm using is correct(given below). or if there is something else i'm missing

```
**Service**

<tr>
    <td>GET_WORKFLOW_HISTORY_EMAIL_DETAILS</td>
    <td>Service
        33
        null
        null
        null<br>
        !csUnableToGetRevInfo</td>
    <td>5:QWorkflowHistoryEmailDetails:WorkflowActionHistory::Unable to get workflow history</td>
</tr>

**Query**

    <tr> <td>QWorkflowHistoryEmailDetails</td> 
<td>SELECT WorkflowHistory.*,
      Reason.Reason,
      ApprovalType.ApprovalType
      CASE
        WHEN APPROVALTYPE IS NULL
        THEN XPURPOSEFORREJECTION
      END AS APPROVALTYPE,
      CASE
        WHEN NVL(daction,'')='sendTo'
        THEN 'Approve'
      END AS daction
    FROM WorkflowHistory WorkflowHistory,
      Reason Reason,
      ApprovalType ApprovalType
    WHERE UPPER(dDocName)     = UPPER(?)
    AND xPurposeForSubmission = Reason.ReasonID(+)
    </td>
    </td> 
        <td>dDocName varchar</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace from the Content Server log?

What service parameters are you passing in? What does your Java code look like for the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this error is because i have copy/pasted a new query in my query template, i will have to make few more changes either in configuration or any other file, which i'm not sure of. i'm using a simple query, as below, now but getting the same error.Any help on how to add a new query and proceed

```
<td>
SELECT 
 DACTIONDATE
FROM WorkflowHistory
WHERE UPPER(dDocName)     = UPPER(?)
AND daction             IN('SendTo','Approve')
ORDER BY dActionDate DESC,dActionMillis;
</td> 
    <td>dDocName varchar</td>
```

Comment: You have changed the specification of the service - by not including the same columns returned in the original service. Try adding those back into your new query. The fact that you return only the dActionDate without any other detail also makes your resultset look pretty meaningless.
Try adding back the original columns - your query should still work and return your desired results.
Also it is a good idea to copy the service and create your own rather than modify any of the standard services.